# Why does this keep popping up in two seperate windows? (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, photoimage

I've created a very basic word game that I want to create a basic gui for. I am testing a file that will put an image on a canvas and then place text boxes for the words over-top of the image.

I cannot seem to get it to use the same window. The text box shows up in a different window than the image. I've tried many various of how to write this code but cannot seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
"""
Python Delete2.py
"""


from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.original = Image.open('687ee377f1820465b443950055671cb6.png')
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.original)
        self.display = Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.display.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image, anchor=NW, tags="IMG")
        self.display.grid(row=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)     


    def resize(self, event):
        size = (event.width, event.height)
        resized = self.original.resize(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)            
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
        self.display.delete("IMG")
        self.display.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image, anchor=NW, tags="IMG")
        madlib = Tk()    
        Label(madlib, text="Please pick an Adjective.").grid(row=0)
        e1 = Entry(madlib)
        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Comment: Is the 'text box' you're referring to the `Label`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
Tk()
```

Should only appear once in your code - it's the main window. You call it twice so you have two main windows. Even if you wanted a second window `Toplevel` is what you should be using. I'd keep the root window in your class:

```
self.root = master
```

in `__init__`. Then when you want to embed stuff in this window, then use it!

```
Label(self.root, text="Please pick an Adjective.").grid(row=0)
e1 = Entry(self.root)
```

If you want to embed in the specific frame (**probably the better idea**), just use self - which is already a frame embedded in the root:

```
Label(self, text="Please pick an Adjective.").grid(row=0)
e1 = Entry(self)
```

drop `madlib`.

Comment: Great advice! Thank you, I think I've figured it out! Just trying to tweak everything to fit into my program. Thanks!